# Calculate integral as area

Tags: calculus, area

I am having some issues with this integral

$$\int_{-\sqrt2}^{\sqrt2} \sqrt{2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

The problem I am having is finding $F(x)$ if $f(x)=\sqrt{2-x^2}$

Comment: Then don't find $F$. Your title says "calculate integral as area". What is the shape of the area between the $x$-axis and $f$?

Answer (score 1):

$y^2+x^2 =2$, a circle , centre $(0,0)$, $r =√2.$

The integral is the area of the upper semi circle ($y \ge 0$).

$\int_{-√2}^{√2}\sqrt{2-x^2}dx = πr^2/2 = π .$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

$$\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2} = \frac x2 \left(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right) +\frac{a^2}{2} \arcsin\left( \frac xa \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}:=\int_{-\text{n}}^\text{n}\sqrt{\text{n}^2-x^2}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Let $x=\text{n}\cdot\sin\left(\text{u}\right)$:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}=\text{n}^2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^2\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}=\text{n}^2\cdot\left[\frac{\text{u}+\sin\left(\text{u}\right)\cos\left(\text{u}\right)}{2}\right]_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}=\text{n}^2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\tag2$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\int\sqrt{2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx&=\int1\times\sqrt{2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx\\&=x\sqrt{2-x^2}+\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx\\&=x\sqrt{2-x^2}-\int\frac{2-x^2}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx+\int\frac2{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx\\&=x\sqrt{2-x^2}-\int\sqrt{2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx+\int\frac2{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx.\end{align}You can deal with $\int\frac2{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx$ doing the substitution $x=\sqrt 2y$ and $\mathrm dx=\sqrt2\,\mathrm dy$. Then, your primitive becomes$$\int\frac2{\sqrt{2-2x^2}}\sqrt2\,\mathrm dy=2\arcsin y=2\arcsin\left(\frac x{\sqrt2}\right).$$Therefore$$\int\sqrt{2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{x\sqrt{2-x^2}}2+\arcsin\left(\frac x{\sqrt2}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The graph of the function $f(x)=\sqrt{2-x^2}$ is the upper semicircle of radius $\sqrt{2}$, center at origin. You will know how to find the area of the circle.