# What is the area of the set $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \leq 1$?

Tags: calculus, geometry, definite-integrals, conic-sections, area

> **Problem:** Let $a, b$ be positive real constants. Calculate the area of the set $$\mathcal{E} = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \leq 1 \right\}$$

I am able to approach the problem with logical thinking like that:

> For $a=b=1$ the set describes an unit circle. We can write the
>   condition as  $$ \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2 +
> \left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2 $$ which makes clear that the constants
>   $a,b$ stretch the circle in $x,y$ direction. Thus we have an ellipse
>   with the axis $a$ and $b$. The equation for the area of an ellipse is
>   know to be $A = \pi a b$.

However, I guess that I am supposed to apprach the problem with some more general method (e.g. integrals, etc.). So how would I solve this problem in a more *formal* way? E.g. for sets with conditions like that in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area that you want to compute is$$2b\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\,\mathrm dx.$$Doing the substitution $x=at$ and $\mathrm dx=a\,\mathrm dt$, you get the integral$$2ab\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt.$$But a primitive of $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ is $\frac12\left(t\sqrt{1-t^2}+\arcsin t\right)$. So,$$\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt=\frac12\left(\arcsin(1)-\arcsin(-1)\right)=\frac\pi2$$and therefore your area is $\pi ab$, as you guessed.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how did you get from the problem to the first integral? I would be glad if you could explain it in general, like what would you do if there was a different equation?

Comment: @SimonMueller From $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\leqslant1$, I got$$-b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\leqslant y\leqslant b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}.$$Therefore, that area that you are interested in is the area between the graphs of the functions $\pm b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$, which is$$2b\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks. And how would you proceed if you had a condition similar to that in general, like: $\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : f(x,y) \leq c \}$?

Comment: @SimonMueller I am not aware of any general way of dealing with that.

Comment: Ok, one last question: Can you explain a bit further how you got from the equation to your first integral? This seems like a big jump to me.

Comment: If you have two functions $\alpha,\beta\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $(\forall x\in[a,b]):\alpha(x)\leqslant\beta(x)$, then the area btween the graphs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is$$\int_a^b\beta(t)-\alpha(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$In my specific case,$$\alpha(t)=-b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\text{ and }\beta(t)=b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}.$$

Comment: How did you get from your integral to $\arcsin(1) - \arcsin(-1)$? Well, I am trying to solve the integral with $\sqrt{1 - t^2}$ with substitution with $z = \sin(u)$ to get to an integral with $\cos^2(u)$ and from that to get to your result of $\pi/2$. So how did you do it?

Comment: @SimonMueller SInce $\displaystyle\int\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt=\frac12\left(t\sqrt{1-t^2}+\arcsin(t)\right)$,\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt&=\frac12\left(1\times\sqrt{1-1^2}+\arcsin(1)\right)-\frac12\left((-1)\times\sqrt{1-(-1)^2}+\arcsin(-1)\right)\\&=\frac12\arcsin(1)-\frac12\arcsin(-1)\\&=\frac12\left(\frac\pi2+\frac\pi2\right)\\&=\frac\pi2.\end{align}

Comment: Ok, I understand everything except your very first step. How do you get from the integral to the form in which $\arcsin$ occurs? Is this obvious and I am missing something or do you look this integral form up somewhere...

Comment: @SimonMueller That is something that I already knew. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490475/calculate-integral-as-area/2490495#2490495) that I also posted yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The area is
$$
\iint\limits_{\mathcal{E}}dx\,dy
$$
With the substitution $x=a\rho\cos\varphi$, $y=b\rho\sin\varphi$ (with $\rho\ge0$ and $0\le\varphi<2\pi$), the limitation on $x$ and $y$ for $(x,y)\in\mathcal{E}$ become
$$
\frac{a^2\rho^2\cos^2\varphi}{a^2}+\frac{b^2\rho^2\sin^2\varphi}{b^2}\le 1
$$
that is, $\rho^2\le1$ and so $0\le\rho\le1$; no further limitation on $\varphi$ is implied.

<sup>Why that substitution? Because we *do* know the set $\mathcal{E}$ is an ellipse, don't we?</sup>

The Jacobian is $ab\rho$, thus the integral becomes
$$
\iint\limits_{\substack{\rho\in[0,1]\\\varphi\in[0,2\pi]}}
  ab\rho\,d\rho\,d\varphi
=
ab\int_0^{2\pi}\biggl(\int_0^1 \rho\,d\rho\biggr)\,d\varphi=\pi ab
$$

Comment: Thanks. So to perform these steps you have to know that the equation describes an ellipse, correct?

Comment: @SimonMueller Not necessarily, but of course it helps.

Comment: Ok, but you got to your substitution because you knew that it was an ellipse, correct?

Comment: @SimonMueller Well , yes, but it’s not so important: you just have to normalize the sine and cosine to use the fundamental identity.

Comment: THanks, what do you mean by normalize?

Comment: @SimonMueller By using $x=a\rho\cos/varphi$, the $a$ factor cancels with the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Parametrize: $x=a \cos(\theta)$,  $ y= b\sin(\theta),$  $0\le \theta \lt 2π.$

1st quadrant:

$\int_{0}^{a} ydx =$

$\int_{π/2}^{0} b\sin(\theta)(-a\sin(\theta))d\theta=$

$-ab\int_{π/2}^{0}\sin^2(\theta)d\theta=$

$ab\int_{0}^{π/2}\sin^2(\theta)d\theta.$

Note:

$ \int_{0}^{π/2}\sin^2(\theta)d\theta =$

$\int_{0}^{π/2}\cos^2(\theta)d\theta.$

Also:

$\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1.$

Now integrating LHS and RHS from $0$ to $π/2:$

$\rightarrow:$

$\int_{0}^{π/2}\sin^2(\theta)d\theta = π/4.$

Finally:

Area of the ellipse : $4 (π/4)ab =πab.$